# Can I add variable into ScriptsListener code?

Tags: photoshop-scripting

**I Have photoshop generated script which change current layer name to `NewName`**

**Question : It is posible to change that static value to variable value**

Here is Code

```
function Rename() {
  // Set
  function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Trgt'));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc2.putString(cTID('Nm  '), "NewName");
    desc1.putObject(cTID('T   '), cTID('Lyr '), desc2);
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };
```

All i want is to remove that `"NewName" String` and put `variable` defined from outside of function like

```
var DynamicName = prompt("Your Name","");
```

**so instead of that `NewName` i want to call `DynamicName` Variable! is that possible?**
I want this cuz sometimes i need to change document name or layer name from my old stored variable from script.

Comment: Semi off-topic, but looking at where this piece of code is going... Maybe you'd be interested in this script I put in github recently: https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-Rename-Layers-Script

Comment: @Sergey Kristiy where did you learnt javascript on high level??and did you learned all languages like html css to make extensions?

Comment: @Joonas thanks but i hate script UI ( well i love it but i hate user input part) i made around 15 scripts and all of them are least user input type; when it comes to raname i always inherit it from original file or psd name etc but your script it great though :)

Comment: I sorta linked the script in hopes you could use it as an example in building your own. Like for instance the way I rename a layer in my script is with a one liner: `app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name = "New name";`, which does exactly the same thing as your Action Manager code in the question. That said, Action Manager code is typically faster. — People use scriptui because they need some input from the user... There's not many other uses. The only one I can think of is a progress bar... I think you are telling me you do after all dislike all of scriptui ;)

Comment: @Joonas i don't dislike scriptUI at all in fact even i need to use it sometimes :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFhGz.png but the thing i avoid it to use it at least as possible XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in any other language, in javascript you can pass parameters to functions:

```
rename(DynamicName); //you're passing a parameter DynamicName to function rename()

function rename(newName) { //newName will be a variable name for parameter
    //babla
    desc2.putString(cTID('Nm  '), newName);
    //blabla
};
```

and you can send a number of variables:

```
rename("beautiful layer", 10);

function rename(newName, id) {
    //babla
    desc2.putString(cTID('Nm  '), newName); // your variable
    ref.putIdentifier(cTID('Lyr '), id); //second variable
    //blabla
};
```

or if your variable is defined outside `rename()` scope you can use it directly:

```
function rename() {
    //babla
    desc2.putString(cTID('Nm  '), DynamicName); // your variable
    //blabla
};
```

I'd recommend to do course on the JS on codeacademy or something similar to learn about it, it won't take more than an hour for basics like this.

Comment: well for current script the stuff working but i used the same thing few days ago while making my extension and oddly don't know why i was failing :) anyway this one works now! btw did you tried making extensions or generators??

Comment: extensions yes: https://gumroad.com/kritskiy ; generators no